# Regex to match any word containing all specific letters?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to put together a regex that matches any word containing all specified letters.

For example:

```
a,b

Aaron: not match
Abby: match
Barry: match
Bobb: not match
Alley: not match
Abel: match
Bella: match
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why this must be a regex? It's much simpler to test each letter separately.

Answer (score 7):

```
(?=\w*a)(?=\w*b)\w+
```

Check that there's an "a", and a "b", before you get to a space or non-word character. Then capture all the characters until the end of the word.

Comment: @faalbane are you sure? It works right for me. What program / language are you testing with?

Comment: JavaScript searching through a json_encoded PHP array

Comment: `"no aa bb ab no aa bb ba".match(/(?=\w*a)(?=\w*b)\w+/g);` gives me: `["ab", "ba"]`

Comment: IMO, `(?=.*a)(?=.*b).+` can be more generic here, And instead of other answers this is more useful for `a,b,c,d` when OP said `a,b` is an example of containing all specified letters ;).

Comment: @shA.t The OP asked to match words, not lines. So I think `\w` or `\S` is more appropriate than dot.

Comment: As I said it is more generic and for finding words yours within `\b...\b` is making more sens ;).

Comment: @shA.t Right. I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward approach.

```
(.*[Aa].*[bB])|(.*[Bb].*[Aa])
```

This will require that there is at least an 'a' and a 'b'.

You can find more information and tutorials on these and other topics [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: What if you have a line like this: `Aaron bobby` ?

Comment: Should capture that.  Or are you focused on the capital A?  If so, `(?=.*[aA])`

Comment: Oh!  Hmm.. Let me test it out.. hang on

Comment: Ok, sorry.  Tested this one out.  The look around wasn't working as I expected.  This does two lookaheads with alternate possibilities.

Comment: Also, you might find this site useful for interactive testing:  http://regexr.com

Comment: Your answer is nice for `a,b` and awful for `a,b,c,d` ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w*[Aa]\w*[bB]\w*)|(\w*[Bb]\w*[Aa]\w*)
```

The approach by David is what led me to this.  But one of the problems with David's original suggestions is that it requires the match to end with A or B.

Comment: Your answer is nice for `a,b` and awful for `a,b,c,d` ;).

Comment: Awful only if one doesn't like working with permutations :)  But agreed, a and b were only examples. RegEx probably not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I would use (in Python syntax):

```py
word_with_a_and_b = re.compile(r"""
    # Match word having both "a" and "b".
    \b            # Anchor to start of word.
    (?=[^\Wa]*a)  # Assert word contains an "a".
    (?=[^\Wb]*b)  # Assert word contains a "b".
    \w+           # Match the word having both "a" and "b".
    \b            # Anchor to end of word.
    """, re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
```