# regex containing all specific character combination in vim

Tags: regex, vim

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35487321/regex-to-match-any-word-containing-all-specific-letters) post, I am able to search for the words containing combinations of all vowels letter.
**regex:**

```
(?=\w*a)(?=\w*e)(?=\w*i)(?=\w*o)(?=\w*u)\w+
```

matches example:

```
abstemious
education
reputation
facetious
```

I then change the following into vim expression as
**regex:**

```
\(\ze\w\{-}a\)\(\ze\w\{-}e\)\(\ze\w\{-}i\)\(\ze\w\{-}o\)\(\ze\w\{-}u\)\w\+
```

changes are

```
( to \(
?= to \ze
* to \{-}
+ to \+
```

But now it only matches serial occurrences like

```
abstemious 
facetious
```

not `education,reputation`

where do I missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This vim-regex should help you:

```
\v(\w{-}a)@=(\w{-}e)@=(\w{-}i)@=(\w{-}o)@=(\w{-}u)@=\w+
```

- The leading `\v` means match in very-magic mode, `:h magic` for details
- look ahead in vim regex is `(...)\@=`, `:h \@=` for details